# UIImage for UIActionSheet button?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

I know that UIActionSheets don't offer that much customization but what I am asking, is that instead of the grayish/white buttons, can I use a green button (my own UIImage)? I can supply my own image with the text already on there that I want; so using a normal UIActionSheet, can I supply my own image on one of the buttons? If so, how should I go upon doing that?

Thanks,
O.Z

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[@huesforalice](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7784350/6296561) is right - the cleanest way would be to create your own replacement of UIActionSheet. Basically you have 3 options:

1. A real replacement: You create a UIActionSheet-subclass to be protocol-compatible to ´UIActionSheetDelegate´. This would allow you to use it exactly as a UIActionSheet — but it might be a costly process to figure out when and why a UIActionSheet will call the delegates method implementation.
2. Even go a bit further and also extend the protocol. This will give you more possibilities, how to use it (i.e. allow picker to be used via new protocol methods), but will be even harder.
3. The most easiest way will be to create a very own implementation, that doesn't rely on UIActionSheet nor it's protocol — but it won't replace real UIActionSheet, in the meaning that you cannot drop it into your project and expect it to work. But you will have the highest degree on freedom.

I would recommend 3. [I found a project, that is working like that](https://github.com/4marcus/WMActionSheet). But be warned: It shows you how to do it in general, but has some poor underlying design-decisions:

- It uses a method

  ```
  - (void) addButtonWithTitle: (NSString*) buttonTitle buttonId: (NSInteger) buttonId textColor: (UIColor*) textColor textShadowColor: (UIColor*) textShadowColor backgroundColor: (UIColor*) buttonBackgroundColor increasedSpacing: (BOOL) spacing
  ```

  Instead — IMHO — it should be

  ```
  - (void) addButton: (UIButton*) button;
  ```

  So you can add buttons with different designs more flexible, and don't depend for a section id, what is totally unnecessary, as the object has its own identity as an object already.
- The method `[actionSheet showWithAnimation:YES];` should be called
  `show`or `showAnimated:` as `…withAnimation:` usually takes a block to perform a custom animation.

Comment: I looked at that project but it doesn't have that Apple look to it, I know it is asking a lot but thats what I want it to look like in the end. Are you sure there is no way to subclass the UIActionSheet and do it that way?

Answer (score 2):

This ist not possible using UIActionSheet and the documented methods. You could write your own actionsheet, which you then probably would add to the main window and animate to slide up. Possibly there is a way to do what you want by analyzing the actionsheets private view hierarchy and adding custom buttons, but you have to keep in mind, that private view hierarchies may change from one iOS Version to another, so your app might break or might even get rejected from apple.